# 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, pdo

SQL Query:

> INSERT INTO tributos_prod (codigo, ncm, descricao, preco, quantidade,
>   v_total, situacao_trib_icms, origem_trib_icms, aliquota_icms,
>   credito_icms, situacao_trib_pis, valor_base_pis, aliquota_pis,
>   valor_pis, situacao_trib_cofins, valor_base_cofins, aliquota_cofins,
>   valor_cofins, aliquota_interestadual, percent_prov_part,
>   icms_part_uf_dest, icms_part_uf_rmt, icms_fcp_uf_dest, id_nfe)
>   VALUES(:codigo, :ncm, :descricao, :preco, :quantidade, :v_total,
>   :situacao_trib_icms, :origem_trib_icms, :aliquota_icms, :credito_icms,
>   :situacao_trib_pis, :valor_base_pis, :aliquota_pis, :valor_pis,
>   :situacao_trib_cofins, :valor_base_cofins, :aliquota_cofins,
>   :valor_cofins, :aliquota_interestadual, :percent_prov_part,
>   :icms_part_uf_dest, :icms_part_uf_rmt, :icms_fcp_uf_dest, :id_nfe)

```
try {
    $query = $conecta->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':codigo',$codigo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':ncm',$ncm,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':descricao',$descricao,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':preco',$preco,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':v_total',$v_total,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':situacao_trib_icms',$situacao_trib_icms,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':origem_trib_icms',$origem_trib_icms,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':aliquota_icms',$aliquota_icms,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':credito_icms',$credito_icms,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':situacao_trib_pis',$situacao_trib_pis,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':valor_base_pis',$valor_base_pis,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':aliquota_pis',$aliquota_pis,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':valor_pis',$valor_pis,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':situacao_trib_cofins',$situacao_trib_cofins,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':valor_base_cofins',$valor_base_cofins,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':aliquota_cofins',$aliquota_cofins,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':valor_cofins',$valor_cofins,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':aliquota_interestadual',$aliquota_interestadual,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':percent_prov_part',$percent_prov_part,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':icms_part_uf_dest',$icms_part_uf_dest,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':icms_part_uf_rmt',$icms_part_uf_rmt,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':icms_fcp_uf_dest',$icms_fcp_uf_dest,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':id_nfe',$nNFe,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();  
}catch(PDOExcepetion $erro){
    echo -1;
}
```

Estrutura SQL `tributos_prod`:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_nfe` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ncm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preco` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `v_total` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantidade` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao_trib_icms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origem_trib_icms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aliquota_icms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credito_icms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao_trib_pis` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_base_pis` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aliquota_pis` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_pis` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao_trib_cofins` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_base_cofins` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aliquota_cofins` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_cofins` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aliquota_interestadual` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent_prov_part` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icms_part_uf_dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icms_part_uf_rmt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icms_fcp_uf_dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_nfe` (`id_nfe`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nfe` FOREIGN KEY (`id_nfe`) REFERENCES `nfe` (`id`)
```

Estrutura SQL `nfe`:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_nfe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_emitente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_pessoa` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `n_cad` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_transportadora` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ambiente` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cfop` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serie` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_emissao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_saida_entrada` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_emissao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finalidade` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf_cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transportadora` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metodo_pagamento` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `infs_fisco` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `infs_contribuinte` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cuf` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnf` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chave` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recibo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protocolo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modalidade_frete` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_contribuinte` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_venda` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itens` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qt_itens` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `especie` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qt_volumes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `peso_liquido` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `peso_bruto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desconto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_doc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_impressao_danfe` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cons_final` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seq_evento` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chaveReferenciada` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bwdbwd_emissor_nfe`.`tributos_prod`, CONSTRAINT `fk_nfe` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_nfe`) REFERENCES `nfe` (`id`))'

-

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bwdbwd_emissor_nfe`.`tributos_prod`, CONSTRAINT `fk_nfe` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_nfe`) REFERENCES `nfe` (`id`))

Já busquei utilizar na `query` : `:VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Passando a gerar o seguinte erro:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was
>   not defined

Comment: O erro `SQLSTATE[HY093]` geralmente cai em ou vc tem mais placeholders que valores ou o contrario ou tem algum nome digitado errado. Já o erro principal (nesse que vc deve se concentrar) `SQLSTATE[23000]` o valor em `id_nfe` pode não existir na tabela `nfe`

Comment: Olá @rray, exatamente isso rsrs'. Estou realizando um `insert` para um valor de `id_nfe` que não existe na tabela `nfe`. Obrigado.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado com o erro, mas considere fazer os binds com um array e `for`, que esse código fica difícil de manter.